# How is export SQL data having 5 million rows in CSV

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, presto

I use Presto to query my SQL. I need to export it as a CSV file, but only 1048576 rows appear when I do so. Is it possible to export all 5 million rows? what other ways I can explore

Comment: Are you sure there are only 1,048,576 rows? That happens to be the maximum number of rows Excel can display. Are you opening the csv with Excel? Try opening it with another program, like Notepad++

Comment: @VvdL Yes, only 1+ M rows. My client wanted me to export CSV in excel. Notepad works
 Thank you for responding to my question.